# return value undefined for following function protractor typescript

Tags: typescript, protractor, return-value

If I call the following function it returns undefined instead of column text. Any help is really appreciated

```
async verifyCreateAuditReport(FieldValue?: string) {

    await this.auditCriteriaReport.all(by.tagName('tr')).then(function (rows) {
        browser.logger.info("Row Count::" + rows.length);
        rows.forEach(function (row: ElementFinder) {
            row.all(by.tagName('td > span')).then(function (cols) {
                browser.logger.info("Column Count::" + cols.length);

                if (cols.length > 0) {
                    cols.forEach(function (col: ElementFinder) {
                        col.getText().then(function (columnText) {
                            if (columnText == FieldValue) {
                                //browser.logger.info("Column Text is::" + columnText);
                                //return Promise.resolve(columnText);
                                return columnText;

                            }
                        });

                    });
                }

            });
        });
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you're misunderstanding some key JavaScript/TypeScript concepts here.

First, your use of async/await is wrong. If you're using a `.then`, you don't need async/await.

Second, I think you're assuming that just calling a function will return the value from your promise, but that is wrong. You need to explicitly say `return` at every function from which you want a value returned.

Third, `forEach` actually returns nothing (i.e. `undefined`). You should be using `map` instead if you want to "map" each element in one list to a different list.

At any rate, this code is very nested, and I would first suggest breaking it out into separate functions, so that we can dissect what's going on here. But here is what I believe you're trying to accomplish.

```js
// This function will get all values with the tagName ('tr') an send them to processList
function verifyCreateAuditReport(fieldValue?: string): Promise<ElementFinder[]> {
    return this.auditCriteriaReport.all(by.tagName('tr')).then((rows) => processRowList(rows, fieldValue))
}

// This function will take all the rows, and, for each column in each row, 
// it'll check if the text is equal to the field value, and push it to `retval` if so.
// Then we return `retval`, which is a list of `ElementFinder`
function processRowList(rows: ElementFinder[], fieldValue?: string): Promise<ElementFinder[]> {
   return rows.all(by.tagName('td > span')).then(async (cols) => {
       const retval: ElementFinder[] = [];

       for (const col of cols) {
           const columnText = await col.getText();
           if (columnText === fieldValue) {
              retval.push(columnText);
           }
       }

       return columnText;
   })
}
```

As a final note, I'd suggest using `===` instead of `==`. You might want to Google that, but `===` is strict equality, which is better for type safety and such. Let me know if you have any questions! You're original code was quite confusing, but I hope I cleared up some concepts.